# Citing in Beamer: Year depiction problem in the reference slide

Tags: beamer, biblatex, apa-style

I am preparing a presentation with beamer package with multiple citations. Therefore I have decided to use the following packages:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}       
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-UoN}   
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}
```

Within the cited slide I have no problems, however in the references slide, which I produces via:

```
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]   
\frametitle{References}   
\printbibliography  
\end{frame}
```

The year is not shown. I have compiled the bib and tex files multiple times. Unfortunately no luck. The citation in the slide stays as:

[image: Citation Slide]

And the reference slide as :

[image: Reference Slide]

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Note: bib entry for this reference is like the following:

```
@phdthesis{beall2003role,
title={The role of reverse auctions in strategic sourcing},
author={Beall, Stewart},
year={2003},
school={Arizona State University}
}
```

In the definition frame I call it with:

lower priced bids during a scheduled time period.'' \cite{beall2003role}

And the reference frame looks like the following:

```
\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Could you show the bib file for this reference and how you call it in the beamer frame?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please edit the details of the reference in to your question.

Comment: What happens if you remove the apa style and use the default style instead?

Comment: Thank you @pluton apparently APA was the problem. As soon as I removed it the problem is solved.

Comment: but do you really need the apa style for you bibliography?

Comment: What exactly is `american-UoN.lbx` as in `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-UoN}`. The `biblatex-apa` styles needs some macros defined in `<language>-apa.lbx`, so one always has to load `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`. So your construction will only work if `american-UoN.lbx` provides the macros necessary...

Comment: Any news here? Does it work with `ameican-apa`? What exactly is `american-UoN`?

Comment: @pluton I wanted to work with APA because it is easier for the presentation followers to read the references as I go. But I decided to solve the problem with giving a reference handout.

Comment: @moeve I tried also with american - apa, no luck but maybe it was my coding

Comment: instead of calling `biblatex` with the `apa` style, you might want to go for the `biblatex-apa` package instead, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa?lang=en.

Comment: @pluton `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` is the correct call for `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: @AysegulEngin That is weird. Maybe an update helps.

Comment: @moewe updated today to texlive 2015 maybe that solved my problem

Comment: @moewe ok, I wasn't sure.

Comment: @pluton - Thanks for the comments and help for the recap biblatex-apa package got me exactly the results I wanted. 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
 is how I called the package

Comment: so `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-UoN}` was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `biblatex-apa` one needs to include a call for `biblatex-apa`'s language files. Amongst others, these `.lbx` files contain `biblatex-apa`'s date macros that are used to format the dates in the bibliography.

After loading `biblatex`, a line aking the lines of `\DeclareLanguageMapping{<language>}{<language>-apa}` should be added; in our example that would be

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```